# Fabric event listener unable to capture endorsement failure scenario

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have coded below logic to use fabric network event listener which will listen to transaction commit. However, it is working fine when transaction endorsed successfully but not when transaction endorsed unsuccessfully. Kindly let me know if I am missing something.

**Code snapshot:**

```
const transaction = networkObj.contract.createTransaction('addOrg');

const tx_id = transaction.getTransactionID().getTransactionID();


await transaction.addCommitListener((err: any, txId: any, status: any, blockHeight: any) => {

  console.log('inside listener');

  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return
  }

  if (status === 'VALID') { 
    console.log('transaction committed');
    console.log('txId: ',txId,'status: ',status,'blockHeight: ',blockHeight);
    console.log('transaction committed end');
  } else {
    console.log('err transaction failed');
    console.log(status);
  }
});

transaction.submit(OrgAdd.organization, OrgAdd.orgShortName, OrgAdd.orgType, OrgAdd.industryType)

let responseMessage: ResponseMessage = new ResponseMessage({ message: tx_id });

console.log('before return');

return responseMessage;
```

Logs when transaction is endorsed successfully vs unsuccessfully.

Successful:

```
Connected to mychannel. 
Connected to contract.  p2pmembers
Done connecting to network.
OrgAdd:  {
  organization: 'Manufacturer 10',
  orgShortName: 'MF10',
  orgType: 'manufacturer',
  industryType: 'Electronics'
}
before return
inside listener
transaction committed
<<txId:>>  7b1767397a9821e0e2e0b16c7f7ad4ada9d15a8a7b838c5cc542be50e260d497 <<status:>>  VALID <<blockHeight:>>  116
transaction committed end
```

Unsuccessful

```
Connected to mychannel. 
Connected to contract.  p2pmembers
Done connecting to network.
OrgAdd:  {
  organization: 'Manufacturer 10',
  orgShortName: 'MF10',
  orgType: 'manufacturer',
  industryType: 'Electronics'
}
before return
2020-06-22T11:32:13.973Z - warn: [DiscoveryEndorsementHandler]: _build_endorse_group_member >> G0:0 - endorsement failed - Error: transaction returned with failure: Error: MF10 organization does exist
2020-06-22T11:32:13.975Z - error: [DiscoveryEndorsementHandler]: _endorse - endorsement failed::Error: Endorsement has failed
```

Answer (score 1):

If endorsement fails (or the send to the orderer fails) then the call to `transaction.submit()` will throw an error. Note that `transaction.submit()` is an **async** function so you should be calling it with `await transaction.submit()`. Without the await you will have an unhandled promise rejection.

Note too that the call to `transaction.submit()` returns the response payload from the transaction invocation so, unless your transaction function doesn't return any payload, you should be capturing that response:

```
const response = await transaction.submit(OrgAdd.organization, OrgAdd.orgShortName, OrgAdd.orgType, OrgAdd.industryType);
```

Typically you don't need to do your own commit listening as the call to `transaction.submit()` does this for you. You can change the default behaviour so submit does not wait for commit events, or change the strategy it uses to decide when a commit is successful, but by default it will be doing that commit waiting for you. If the commit fails, `transaction.submit()` will again throw an error. The error that comes out has proposal responses attached to allow you to investigate the reason for failure.

```
try {
    const response = await transaction.submit(OrgAdd.organization, OrgAdd.orgShortName, OrgAdd.orgType, OrgAdd.industryType);
    // Successful transaction endorsement and commit
} catch (error) {
    // Failure to endorse or commit
}
```

Some reasons why you might need to use the kind of pattern you are describing with a separate commit listener are:

1. You want to process the transaction response immediately after the transaction is sent to the orderer but still check for commit success at the client end.
2. You want to do checking for commit success entirely asynchronously; perhaps in a different process for performance reasons.

These are both atypical cases and may result in subsequent transactions seeing unexpected state if they are interacting with the same ledger keys as the previous transaction and are processed by peers that have not yet committed that previous transaction. In general, just awaiting the one line call to `transaction.submit()` and letting it handle waiting commit events for you will give you the best experience.

Answer (score 0):

The Fabric model for transacting follows 'endorse' (or, execute), 'order', 'commit'.  A proposal is sent for endorsement at one or more peers, if the endorsements are successful, the client assembles the proposal and endorsements into a transaction which is submitted to ordering.  Once the transaction is ordered, the peers receive it in a block and perform validation (ensuring that the correct endorsements are present) and version control checks (ensuring that all of the inputs to execution are unmodified).  For a detailed architectural review see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.10228v2).

Event listeners are for 'commit events', which are emitted in that last stage where the peer checks to see if the transaction is valid/consistent.  If the initial endorsement fails, then the client never submits the transaction to ordering, and therefore, no commit event occurs.

You may be confusing "endorsement failure" with "endorsement policy failure".  An endorsement policy failure occurs when the client does not seek enough endorsements, or endorsements from the right peers, but submits the transaction anyway.  You will see an event with a failure in this case, but there was no error at endorsement time.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the confusion. So, commit listener can never catch the endorsement error i.e. even error thrown due to validation in Smart Contract... Blockchain transaction moves through flow of endorse, order and commit which result in higher response time and even higher when the transaction is submitted from UI portal. I would like to free UI quickly after submitting the transaction so user doesn't have to wait and can perform the next transaction, hence I am trying event logic. Do we have some features \ logic which we can leverage to achieve this. Like in Ethereum.

Comment: If your UI is interacting with the a server-component which is leveraging the SDK, then the easiest thing to do would be to simply have that server-component capture the failure and expose it as an event to the UI.  Most likely, your server-component is already trying to surface the commit events to the UI in a similar way, so, it would be a matter of multiplexing both failure paths (endorsement, and commit failures) into the same path.

Comment: Thank you Jason! But, how can we capture the failure because addCommitListener works for commit only doesn't capture the endorsement failures? Also, I have tried using addContractListener to send success or failure (when some condition fails to meet) as message from smartContract to SDK. It’s working, however it’s creating empty block incase of failure because transaction is considered as endorsed because of no “throw error”. So, in short which method\process can help me to capture failure scenario without creating an empty block on Fabric.